# eslint no-unused-vars doesn't catch unused React Fragment imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have a `.js` file with `import React, { Component, Fragment }` at the top. The only import that is used is React itself but eslint with `no-unused-vars` set to "warn" only catches the unused import for `Component`.

Comment: Double checking: you don't have fragments in use in your component with `<>` ?

Comment: ah yes, i see the fragment shorthand usage is preventing the linter from catching it. thanks!